# Why does keras predict_classes fail when predict_generator works on the same dataset on a multi-class classification problem?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have 6 classes of images and am trying to train a model using Transfer Learning based on MobileNetv2.

I start by creating an ImageDataGenerator which I then split into separate train and test flows using the 'subset' feature.

```
# Rescale all images by 1./255 and apply image augmentation
train_test_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.5)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_test_dir,  # Source directory for the training images
                target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True,
                class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training')

# Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator
validation_generator = train_test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                train_test_dir, # Source directory for the validation images
                target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                batch_size=1,shuffle=False,
                class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation')
```

Then the model is created and trained:

```
# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

class_count = len(train_generator.class_indices)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs = 5
steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n // batch_size
validation_steps = validation_generator.n // batch_size

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                              epochs=epochs,
                              workers=4,
                              #pickle_safe=True,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

So far so good. However, although I can get the raw softmax output from `predict_generator`:

```
class_predictions = model.predict_generator(
    validation_generator,
    20)
```

I can't get anything from predict_classes:

```
class_predictions = model.predict_classes(
    validation_generator
)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-7afb08b94298> in <module>()
      1 class_predictions = model.predict_classes(
----> 2     validation_generator
      3 )

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in predict_classes(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
    324         A numpy array of class predictions.
    325     """
--> 326     proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    327     if proba.shape[-1] > 1:
    328       return proba.argmax(axis=-1)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    924         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    925         workers=workers,
--> 926         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    927 
    928   def reset_metrics(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in predict(self, model, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    637               workers=1,
    638               use_multiprocessing=False):
--> 639     model._validate_or_infer_batch_size(batch_size, steps, x)
    640     return predict_generator(
    641         model,

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_or_infer_batch_size(self, batch_size, steps, x)
   1831             'The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given '
   1832             'input type. Received input: {}, batch_size: {}'.format(
-> 1833                 x, batch_size))
   1834       return
   1835 

ValueError: The `batch_size` argument must not be specified for the given input type. Received input: <keras_preprocessing.image.directory_iterator.DirectoryIterator object at 0x7ffa1da58358>, batch_size: 32
```

This worked fine for a previous binary_crossentropy model but for this categorical_crossentropy model, predict_classes doesn't work.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`predict_classes` is only available for Sequential models and expects a numpy array not a generator object.

```
Arguments
x   input data, as a Numpy array or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs).
batch_size  integer.
verbose     verbosity mode, 0 or 1.
```

It's better to avoid this, as the doc says:

> Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed after 2021-01-01. Instructions for updating: Please use instead:* np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1), if your model does multi-class classification (e.g. if it uses a softmax last-layer activation).* (model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32"), if your model does binary classification (e.g. if it uses a sigmoid last-layer activation).

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

Comment: The deprecation message is missing from the online docs nowadays, but the method aforementioned is still available.